# Un-fork GitHub project into new GitHub project not associated with the original

Tags: github, git-fork

A few months ago, I forked a GitHub project (let's call it "OriginalProject") to my GitHub account (let's call it "FirstFork").

Forking it was, in retrospect, a mistake, because my changes in FirstFork will almost certainly never be merged back into the original project (in other words, it's a permanent divergence). At the time, I wrongly thought that forks were just a polite way to let the original project's owner know you were using it.

What I want to do:

1. Disassociate FirstFork from OriginalProject, then
2. Re-fork OriginalProject to a new fork under my account called SecondFork (so I can make changes to SecondFork that actually MIGHT get merged back to OriginalProject someday).

Note that I **don't** want to delete FirstFork or its Git history, nor do I want to obfuscate its origins as a branch of OriginalProject... I just don't want it to be my account's one and only allowed fork of OriginalProject.